# Remove Empty Lines with a Block of Function

Tags: regex, notepad++

Can you suggest me a regex to remove empty lines within the block of func [func{remove empty lines }]. I am using notepad++

there is some confusion :

```
FUNC1()
{
int x;

int y;
CallFunC();

}

FUNC2()
{
int x;
int y;

CallFunC();

}

FUNC3()
{
int y;
int x;

CallFunC();

}

FUNC4()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}
```

Consider i have above scenerio. I need to delete the empty lines from such functions

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(?<!\})\n\n`
Replace by: `\n`

If you are dealing with a windows file, change the `\n` to `\r\n`:

Find what: `(?<!\})\r\n\r\n`
Replace by: `\r\n`

You could also use:

Find what: `(?<!\})\R\R`
Replace by: `\r\n`

This is replacing two line break `\n\n` with a single one `\n` only if there are no `}`before them so it leaves the line break after the end of a function.

Comment: doesn't work.. finds empty line after '}' i.e end of function

Comment: hi !!! thanks but it doesn't work .. it does not remove the empty lines between the opening and closing braces .. instead it removes the empty lines found after closing braces

Comment: @user2598064: I try the regex on your examples and it works as expected (I guess). Could you show some examples where it doesn't work and what is the expected result?

Comment: hi !! I cross checked it... it works for both !! Some how the behaviour is different in Eclipse & Notepad++. Thanks it works fine in Eclipse.. In Notepad i have selected wrap around optin and regex. Anything else i need to choose. Please if u can elaborate the regex u provided will be beneficial

Comment: @user2598064: May be you have to replace `\n` by `\r\n`.

Comment: hi M42 .. can u Please elaborate the expression for my understanding

Comment: I missed out one more thing the file format .. saved by default was dos... i need to make them "UNIX" Your Solution works fine

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>, this will open the *find and replace window*.

now do the following :

1. Check the *Wrap around* box, and *Extended* box,
2. in *Find what* box, put **`\n\r`**
3. in *Replace with* box, put nothing
4. then *Replace all*
5. Again, in *Find what* box, put **`}\r\n`**
6. in *Replace with* box, put **`}\r\n\r\n`**
7. then *Replace all*

This should do the job.

I have put the sample input and the output I'm getting after both replace.

*Sample Input:*

```
FUNC1()
{
int x;

int y;
CallFunC();
}
FUNC2()
{
int x;
int y;

CallFunC();

}

FUNC3()
{
int y;
int x;

CallFunC();

}

FUNC4()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}
```

*After 1st Replace all:*

```
FUNC1()
{
int x;
int y;
CallFunC();
}
FUNC2()
{
int x;
int y;
CallFunC();
}
FUNC3()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}
FUNC4()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}
```

*After 2nd Replace all:*

```
FUNC1()
{
int x;
int y;
CallFunC();
}

FUNC2()
{
int x;
int y;
CallFunC();
}

FUNC3()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}

FUNC4()
{
int y;
int x;
CallFunC();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the word "remove lines" .. i want to delete the Lines.. can you please look into the updated question.

Comment: @user2598064 : I've updated the answer, with sample input/output. Check whether this works fine or not, and let me know.

Comment: I dont know.. i am trying wht u said on the same exaple... the empty lines keep on incresing between two functions .. consistently,, i say replace all .. second time

Comment: You have to replace once with step 2-4, and once with step 5-7. If you repeat step 5-7, the empty lines between Functions will increase.